# Is it possible to use wildcard with SOLR query field(qf) in WCS?

Tags: solr, wcs

We have multiple product catalogs with respective categories under each catalog, but same or a sub-set of products are included in all the catalogs. By default WCS/WebSphere Commerce applies 'defaultSearch' and 'categoryname' search scopes for IBM_findProductsBySearchTerm profile, causing it to return more and not relevant products for current keyword search.

I could get rid of those items by removing defaultSearch and category name search types from OOB wc-search.xml profile(which would in turn remove those from qf field values during SOLR calls), but would like to know if it's possible to use a wildcard string in qf field something like 100002_* to restrict keyword search to current catalog categories only, and ignore other catalog(s) categories in search and relevancy ranking/scoring.

We would still like SOLR to search current catalog categories, just not include other catalog categories that current customer is not entitled for.

Thanks

Comment: U should be able to restrict the current search to the current catalog and thus to its categories by passing catalogId. Choose the catalogId of the respective sub-catalog  (not the top-level one, since this would include all the other catalogs). Have you tried this

Comment: Yes, we are already passing fq=catalog_id:22333527 to restrict search to current customer or site specific catalog, but noticed that SOLR is returning items that are not relevant to current keyword search, because there exists a category name in some other catalog with all or few of the letters used for the keyword search.

Comment: For example, 'candy' returns items that are no way related to candy since some other customer has cleaning supplies items in a category that has 'candy' word in it, but the cleaning supplies items are in a different category for the current site catalog. How do we prevent SOLR not to add weight score those documents during defaultSearch or categoryname search?

Comment: @awagen, here is the question I posted with more information. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55750681/categoryname-search-in-websphere-commerce-8-solr